# What does an ampersand in an lm formula do?

Tags: r, formula, lm, r-formula

In a linear model (`lm()`) formula with R, what does the ampersand (`&`) do?

For example using a `+` give this result:

```r
x <- 1:10 + rnorm(10)
z <- rep(c(0,4), 5) 
y <- x + z
lm(y ~ x + z)
```

Produces:

```r
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x            z  
 -1.685e-15    1.000e+00    1.000e+00
```

And using an `&` gives this result.

```r
lm(y ~ x & z)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x & z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    x & zTRUE  
      4.666        5.731
```

Lastly, a search for "[r] ampersand formula" on this site produced not hits, please let me know if you found an answer, what terms you used to search for.

Comment: If that's the exact text you searched for, it might be because you misspelled "amper_s_and". Did you see this notation somewhere in a formula?

Comment: Possible it's just a typo - `&` is next to `*` on many keyboard layouts.  `*` does have meaning in a formula, whereas `&` does not.

Comment: @camille just a typo in my question. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I saw somebody else use it, but could not find any documentation. Looks like a typo that doesn't cause R to crash. The person had mistyped it instead of a `+`.  The models give different results, but I was wondering if it was hidden command in R I did not know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In formula, it does nothing, just make independend variabla logical(or zero-one).

```
> lm(y ~ x & z)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x & z)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    x & zTRUE  
      5.287        4.580
```

You can see `x & z` and `as.logical(z)` is identical, that `x` does not have `0` values, so every `x` is `TRUE`.

```
> x & z
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> as.logical(z)
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> as.logical(x)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE



> lm(y ~ as.numeric(as.logical(z)))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ as.numeric(as.logical(z)))

Coefficients:
              (Intercept)  as.numeric(as.logical(z))  
                    5.287                      4.580
```

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say it does nothing, when it clearly produces different outputs and should be used only when the variable (here `z`) is dichotomous.

Comment: @mhovd Well, I used "nothing" as it does not have specific usage only for function `lm`, like `*` and `;` for interaction, `|` for random effects. I appologize for confusing expression.

Comment: I guess you mean `:` for interaction and not `;`.

Comment: @Park thank you for explaining. I saw sombeody use this (by mistake I think) and was wondering if it was hidden command in R I did not know about or simply somebody else's typo that did not cause R to crash.